# Compatibility for Java library methods that require Android API level 9?

Tags: android, java, android-support-library

Some Java library methods like `DecimalFormat.setRoundingMode` have a `@since 1.6` entry in their documentation.

```
/**
...
 * @since 1.6
 */
public void setRoundingMode(RoundingMode roundingMode) {
...
}
```

When I tried to use this method compiled under Android 4.2.2 and JDK 1.6 with my `android:minSdkVersion` set to 7 as shown,

```
myNumberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Android Lint underlined `setRoundingMode` in red for me and told me that

```
Call requires API level 9 (current min is 7): java.text.NumberFormat#setRoundingMode
```

How and *why* can the Android API restrict which Java library methods I can and cannot use? I cleaned my project and the Lint error disappeared. My project compiled with no errors and ran on a device running Android 2.2.3 (API 8).
My program crashed with:

```
05-09 11:32:38.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.text.NumberFormat.setRoundingMode
```

The Android documentation confirms that [setRoundingMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)), [copySign](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#copySign(double,%20double)), and others were added in API level 9. **Does that mean that devices running Android OS level 8 and below are specifically compiled/built with JDK 1.5?**

And I can understand that. **But is it impossible for the Android Support Library (or anything else) to allow us to use these methods?**

Related to [Rounding Half Up with Decimal Format in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072313/rounding-half-up-with-decimal-format-in-android)